# RegEx multiple steps in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the string below:

```
"oxcCFC/video.mp4 "GET /accounts/6/videos/xboxcCFC/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 - 2 697898511 56 56 "-""
```

How would I create a regular expression that first finds "HTTP, then finds "-", and then captures the next indiviual number or consecutive numbers that occurs in the sequence?

I'm trying to use rubular but struggling big time.

Comment: So, given your example, what would be captured?

Comment: What do you mean by "then" or "steps"? Don't you just want the stuff after the "-"?

Comment: I do but their could be circumstances where there is more than one "-" before I get to the "HTTP". So I am trying to figure out if I could skip ahead to the HTTP and then from there skip to the next "-" and then from there select the next number. I dont know if I am thinking about regex properly...

Comment: Given my example the number 2 would be captured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot to go on, but I think it should be something like this:

```
/^.*\s+HTTP.*\s+-\s+(\d+)\s+/
```

A backreference will then hold the value you're after.

Comment: @BC00 Glad it worked.  Do you mean one particular part or the whole thing?  I'll try to add some explanation to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd see if you can use the apachelogregex gem... http://rubydoc.info/gems/apachelogregex/0.1.0/frames

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `/HTTP[^-]*-([\d\s]+)/`
then, call `split` on the result.

This regexp translates to:

"HTTP", followed by any number of non-hyphen characters, followed by a hyphen, followed by the largest string consisting only of digits and spaces.